# Assigning Environment Variables from Consul KV using consul-template

Tags: environment-variables, consul, consul-template, consul-kv

I am very new to consul. I just want to load my environment variables from consul kv using consul-template. I have an consul kv entry having key "iamdbusername". I want to assign its value in an environment variable IAM_DB_USER with the help of consul-template. My application is using the environment variable IAM_DB_USER for getting the database user name.

Any clue in this will be very helpful for me.

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[envconsul](https://github.com/hashicorp/envconsul) can be used to launch a subprocess with environment variables that are populated from Consul.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/67888502/12384224 provides an example of launching a process with envconsul, as well as with an additional tool called Teller.

Comment: Yes it worked but when I want to echo my environment variable then it is showing blank value. Any reason for this???

Comment: Can you share the exact command you're using, and KVs which you're querying from Consul? That'll be helpful to assist you in debugging this. Thanks.

Comment: Sure. Following are the details


```consul kv put iamuser/IAM_PG_DBUSER iamadmin```


```envconsul -pristine -prefix iamuser -once env```


It returns output as: - 
IAM_PG_DBUSER=iamadmin
But when I echo it using ```echo $IAM_PG_DBUSER``` then it is showing blank.

Comment: The `-once` flag was used as an example so that envconsul does not try to perpetually run the `env` command. You will need to run `envconsul` with the name of your actual processs, and without the `-once` flag so that it keeps your process alive. For example, `envconsul -pristine -prefix iamuser /path/to/your-app`.

Comment: Ok, Now i got the point. This means I need to run my application using ```envconsul```. Will you please guide me on my scenario that I am having an ASP .NET CORE 3.1 web application and in it I want to access database using some credentials. Those credentials I put in consul KV. Now My application expects those credentials in some environment variables. Is there any other way to do this which will only set the my desired environment variable so that i can run my application in normal way (without ```envconsul```). Can it be possible using ```consul-template```.

Comment: How does the application read the environment variables? Is it able to load variables which are already set in the shell? If so, you can use consul-template or Teller to render a `.env` file in your application's directory. You can then load those environment variables using `source .env` prior to starting the app. Sorry, its hard to make a more clear recommendation until I understand how the app is currently reading from its environment.

Comment: Thanks @Blake. Now I am able to do this. Thanks for your support.